# Google Places API returning sparse results vs Google Places iPhone app

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am building an application which uses Google Places API to show restaurants near my current location.  For some reason the results are very sparse compared to the results that I can see from the Google Places iPhone application.  For example from my rural home, Google Places app shows the nearest location 2.4 mi away.  The Places API from this lat/long shows the nearest location 15.7 mi away.

Is it possible that "Google Places" the application is not using the Google Places API?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Places App does not use the Google Places API so you will not see the exact same results, however you should see similar results.

**A few tips when using the Places API:**

- The Places API by default sorts returned results in your selected `radius` by `prominence`, not `distance`. If you would like to find the closest places as it sounds like you are trying, use `rankby=distance` in your query with out the `radius` parameter.
- Try using the `keyword` parameter instead of the 'name' parameter, as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/): the 'keyword' parameter is matched against all available fields, including but not limited to name, type, and address, as well as customer reviews and other third-party content, this tends to return more results.

If you adhere to these tips you will most likely get similar results to Places App.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I am finding that the results are dramatically different.  In my nearest city for example, the top 20 results by distance in the Places API covers nearly a 20 mile radius.  If I search in the Places application, the top 20 results are within 5 miles...indicating many more entries.  If I use the Google Map application from my desktop, I get very similar results to the Google Places app.  I'm thinking I should dump the places API and use a maps API instead?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample location and Places API query so I can investigate this. Also are you able to provide a Place that is returned in the Places App that is not returned in the Places API. The  Maps API has a places library that uses the same backend. If you can provide me the above details I will see to it that we find the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris, the results are getting closer.  Here is one sample query (minus our key): 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=30.3637028,-97.7394526&rankby=distance&types=restaurant&sensor=false&key=

This returns a similar result set (actually more results than Places).  One that does not show up in the API query but does in Places is "Cover 3, 2700 W Anderson Ln, 78757".  And this one is closer than some of the other result in the API return.

Comment: I have tested that query using a lat lng distance calculator and all the places that are returned are closer to the provided lat lng that the lat lng of "Cover 3". It seems that the Places API is working as expected. If you find any anomalies, let me know.